# Is there any information database which lists all of the mobile devices and specifications?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, mobile-phones, mobile-devices

Is there any opensource projects or sites which provide the lists of all the mobile devices and specifications?

Comment: do you want only android deivces or all other devices also ?

Comment: All devices..mainly iPhone,android,blackberry,windows

Comment: do you want api (which give response in xml or json) or just want to see the list of devices on web ?

Comment: Yes.. xml format is preferable ..

Answer (score 20):

Maybe this is old but might help someone.i was searching and no good options for this. so made a free restful api to get mobile device descriptions. 6700+ mobile device descriptions available now. you can use it in your applications.

here is the website
https://fonoapi.freshpixl.com/

and github here
https://github.com/shakee93/fonoapi

i just made the php client to access the api. someone can help with other languages too..

Please drop me a message if you can help make it better. we help the community from  community.

Comment: Hello, I gave it a look, seems a very nice job thanks ! However: how can I see the entire result of a query with more than 100 items in the result? thanks again

Comment: Sorry The Api Only Gives Result of 100 max. Target of Api is to provide specification of a mobile device description a 100 result would do it.

Comment: Api is not working in Node.js. It always show undefined result when i query Iphone6s

Comment: Sorry for that please create an issue on appropriate nodejs package. Nodejs is not maintained by me.  php and jquery  versions are maintained by me.

Comment: It is very useful. thanks. Mobile image is not coming, is it any otherway to get images also ?

Answer (score 7):

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) is the industry standard for mobile device information - it's main job is to take a user-agent and match it to a device and attributes, however it can be queried to also get lists of devices and attributes with a little bit of effort.

The actual [WURFL datasource](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wurfl/WURFL/latest/wurfl-latest.zip) is in a flat xml structure and is a little less complicated to get your head around to start with, but using one of the developed APIs will make the learning curve easier.

Comment: my company has launched a free REST API that is the closest you can find to a free database of device profiles (smartphone, tablet, smart tv, etc.). The service is called WURFL Query REST API or QuWURFL for short. The following blog post is an introduction to the REST API:
https://medium.com/@luca.passani/wurfl-query-rest-api-how-to-autofill-smartphone-names-2c63a676e4a3

More information available here: https://docs.scientiamobile.com/documentation/cloud/getting-started-with-wurfl-wurfl-query-rest-api

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at OpenDDR project (removed original link since it is now defunct) - "open and completely free Device Description Repository (with access APIs) available worldwide".

Their [OpenDDR-Resources repository](https://github.com/OpenDDRdotORG/OpenDDR-Resources) seems to contain XML files with device descriptions you're after and provides a link to the last free and open distribution of WURFL file.

Their [other repositories](https://github.com/OpenDDRdotORG) also contain C# and Java implementations of the API.

Comment: http://openddr.org site is dead, now redirects to ad/malware

Comment: Removed link to openddr site, but the GitHub repo contents still containing the files from the project.

Comment: The OpenDDR site is now http://openddr.mobi. Since the GitHub organisation was tied to the old ".org" domain, we decided to create a new one: https://github.com/OpenDDRmobi. You find C#, Java and VB.net implementations by OpenDDR (some based on DeviceMap, they're fully backward compatible with DeviceMap Data if needed) and forks or improvements of other clients for different languages like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

For Android there is a user build database of [device reports](http://www.androidfragmentation.com/database). It seems it is only visible via the web but you can search for different devices and look at their specifications.

Comment: Yes, the old site was taken by domain grabbers (while DeviceMap continued some OpenDDR goals) but the site is now on http://openddr.mobi. Please check it out.