# Is there any API for accessing phone database from a site like GSMARENA?

Tags: database, api, mobile, specifications

I would like to know if is there any API for accessing phone database from a site like GSMARENA or any other site for that matter?
I need it for my offline project and wondering if i can get help?

Comment: Try out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812293/is-there-any-information-database-which-lists-all-of-the-mobile-devices-and-spec

Comment: you can use my fork of "bachors".
you can get all brands, all models and all details. https://github.com/ramtin2025/gsmarena-API I used this for an online mobile store

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/arwinneil/gsmarena-phone-dataset as of 2017